# Combining sets of columns without duplicates but while filling in blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, database

So, suppose I have some data:

| First name | Last name | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Orangeman |  |
| Kathy | Coolidge | Captain |
| Eric | Smarty | Sidekick |

And then another 3 columns of related data:

| First name | Last name | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Orangeman | Pilot |
| Kathy | Coolidge | Captain |
| John | Otherguy | Janitor |

Can I combine these two tables to wind up with all 4 people so that:

1. There aren't two entries for Kathy,
2. John Orangeman gets "Pilot" added without creating a double entry,
3. The two Johns in the first column but with different last names don't get tagged as duplicates

Is this possible in Excel? Would another program (that can export to .xlsx or .csv) be a better choice? I could cobble something together in Python, but I'm trying to keep the workflow simple. Assume only "Position" would ever be blank, and no two people with the same first/last name exist.

Thank you.

Comment: In Excel 2007 you could develop a VBA solution.  In Excel 2010+, you could use either VBA or Power Query.

Comment: if this was a one time process, then excel 2007 should have data->remove duplicates. Just copy the data from second table to first table. After using the remove duplicates command, I would think you need to go back in to determine which semi-duplicate you want to keep ( john orangeman blank or pilot)